# How to block the social websites in centos through proxy?

Tags: centos

I am installed squid in centos system. Blocked the social websites to all ip address through squid in my server systems. But someone access social websites through proxy websites, because lot of proxy sites are there in the internet. I think Proxy websites are encrypted to allow the social sites. Please suggest my question...

Answer (score 1):

Blocking websites is somehow a cat-and-mouse game, and you will have to combine many methods to minimize the number of web proxies that your users can reach/access.

**Method 1 - Blocking common proxy regexes:**

Edit your `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file using your editor of choice and add the following lines:

```
acl regex-prox-sites urlregex –i "/etc/squid/proxy_regex.acl"
http_access deny regex-prox-sites
```

Now, create the file `/etc/squid/proxy_regex.acl` and add the following line:

```
browse.php
view?q=
```

You could also add the word `proxy` on this list, but it could cause false positives. Using this method you will cut user access to webproxies that have the common php filenames above and use those words on any place of the url.

**Method 2 - Use squidGuard and download online provided lists**

This will take some time, and you will probably have to compile squidGuard sources if your disribution does not package it, and use online lists like [Shalla Secure Services](http://www.shallalist.de/). You can refer to squidGuard docs where there is plenty of documentation with the install steps and how to use blacklists from internet.

- [squidGuard Installation](http://www.squidguard.org/Doc/install.html)
- [Basic configuration](http://www.squidguard.org/Doc/configure.html)
- [Extended configuration](http://www.squidguard.org/Doc/extended.html)
- [Configuration examples](http://www.squidguard.org/Doc/examples.html)
- [Ubuntu squidGuard Wiki - Useful stuff](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquidGuard)

After the setup is complete, you will need to add a url rewrite parameter at the end of your `squid.conf` file. Example:

```
echo "url_rewrite_program $(which squidGuard)" >> /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

**Method 3 - Craft your own script to create a blacklists from sites that provide web proxies information.**

This example will download a html file from proxy.org and extract sites from the html.

```
wget -q -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" http://proxy.org/cgi_proxies.shtml -O - |grep "\<option value=\"" | grep -v random | cut -d \" -f 2
```

Note that this simple script will work just with this site, and other proxy providers could have login restrictions or other methods to block you from bulk downloading information.

You could redirect the output of this command to another file, and create a `dstdomain` block on squid following the example of the method 1.